# In Ios 14 Flutter App does not save in Debug mode

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, ios14

recently I updated my iPhone version to IOS 14, but after updating to a newer software version my flutter app not save in debug mode.
(As a simple word, I am run my flutter application on my ios device with a USB cable,
but after removing the USB cable, my application automatically closes and not open again without connection in debug mode.
this issue only arises in IOS 14.
It works fine only if the connection is established in the device with Xcode.)

this issue not arise in other IOS versions like IOS 13.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60657) suggests upgrading flutter (use `flutter upgrade`) or using `flutter run --release`.

Comment: yes its work in release,but what about debug mode(i face issue in there)

Answer (score 2):

It is a new limitation in iOS 14.

"due to changes in debugger mechanisms, once a Flutter debug application is installed on the device (either by using flutter run a Flutter-enabled IDE, or from Xcode), the application can no longer be re-launched by tapping the application’s icon in the home screen in iOS 14 on physical devices."
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-14

If you want to see more details about the issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60657